# How would we extract elements of a list greater than a certain value?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, sorting, order

Say we have a list
`{35,210,67,950,32,365}`
how would we extract all the elements greater than 100 from this list (using a function)? The desired output would be something like
`{950,365,210}`
since I also want the values to be ordered from greatest to least. Is there a way to manipulate Sort or Ordering to get this result??

Answer (score 6):

First apply a function to take elements greater than 100, then apply ReverseSort to get it in greatest-to-least order:

`ReverseSort@Select[GreaterThan[100]]@{35, 210, 67, 950, 32, 365}`

Answer (score 2):

If you like using patterns,

```
l = {35, 210, 67, 950, 32, 365};
Select[l, # > 100 &] //. {a___, b_, c_, d___} /; b < c :> {a, c, b, d}

{950, 365, 210}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice trick if you know that

i) all list members are integers
ii) all members exist in range (e.g. 0 .. 999999).

```
let lowerbound = 0;
let upperbound = 999999;

let the_array = array[lowerbound .. upperbound ] of integers;

(set all array members to zero)

for each list_member in the_list;
  array[list_member] = array[list_member] + 1; 

the_list.clear;

for x = lowerbound to upperbound 
  for y = 1 to array[x].value
    list.Add(x);
```

To put it another way: the `index` of the array is added `value` times to the outputted list in `index` order.

This can easily be modified to ignore numbers above some value.

Answer (score 0):

`Pick` is an alternative to `Select`, as in

```
findGreater[v_, max_]:=ReverseSort[Pick[v, UnitStep[max - v], 0]]
```

For example,

```
findGreater[{35, 210, 67, 950, 32, 365}, 100]
```

> {950, 365, 210}